# Parsing HTML to get text inside an element

Tags: python, html, python-2.x, html-parser

I need to get the text inside the two elements into a string:

```py
source_code = """<span class="UserName"><a href="#">Martin Elias</a></span>"""

>>> text
'Martin Elias'
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Theres several ways to skin the cat here.  What's the end result?  You could do javascript or some server-side parsing.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I searched "python parse html" and this was the first result:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

This code is taken from the python docs

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

    # create a subclass and override the handler methods
    class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
        def handle_endtag(self, tag):
            print "Encountered an end tag :", tag
        def handle_data(self, data):
            print "Encountered some data  :", data

    # instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
                '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

Here is the result:

```
Encountered a start tag: html
Encountered a start tag: head
Encountered a start tag: title
Encountered some data  : Test
Encountered an end tag : title
Encountered an end tag : head
Encountered a start tag: body
Encountered a start tag: h1
Encountered some data  : Parse me!
Encountered an end tag : h1
Encountered an end tag : body
Encountered an end tag : html
```

Using this and by looking at the code in HTMLParser I came up with this:

```
class myhtmlparser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.NEWTAGS = []
        self.NEWATTRS = []
        self.HTMLDATA = []
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.NEWTAGS.append(tag)
        self.NEWATTRS.append(attrs)
    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.HTMLDATA.append(data)
    def clean(self):
        self.NEWTAGS = []
        self.NEWATTRS = []
        self.HTMLDATA = []
```

You can use it like this:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

pstring = source_code = """<span class="UserName"><a href="#">Martin Elias</a></span>"""


class myhtmlparser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.NEWTAGS = []
        self.NEWATTRS = []
        self.HTMLDATA = []
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.NEWTAGS.append(tag)
        self.NEWATTRS.append(attrs)
    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.HTMLDATA.append(data)
    def clean(self):
        self.NEWTAGS = []
        self.NEWATTRS = []
        self.HTMLDATA = []

parser = myhtmlparser()
parser.feed(pstring)

# Extract data from parser
tags  = parser.NEWTAGS
attrs = parser.NEWATTRS
data  = parser.HTMLDATA

# Clean the parser
parser.clean()

# Print out our data
print tags
print attrs
print data
```

Now you should be able to extract your data from those lists easily. I hope this helped!

Answer (score 36):

I recommend using the Python [Beautiful Soup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library.

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

It makes HTML parsing really easy.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source_code = """<span class="UserName"><a href="#">Martin Elias</a></span>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
print soup.a.string
>>> 'Martin Elias'
```

Comment: I know that the question is tagged python-2.x, but I think it should be noted that beautifulsoup only works on python 2.x.

Comment: @LJNielsenDk, beautifulsoup works on both python 2.x and 3.x

Answer (score 6):

Install beautifulsoup and 
You can do like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import  BeautifulSoup
source_code = '"""<span class="UserName"><a href="#">Martin Elias</a></span>"""'
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
print soup.find('span',{'class':'UserName'}).text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using html5lib and XPath, [there is a good question about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5073316/1514681), that answer has an important detail (`namespaceHTMLElements`) to remember to make html5lib behave as expected. I wasted so much time trying to get it to work because I overlooked that I needed to change that.