# python list.append between text

Tags: python, html, list, python-3.x, append

In Python 3, how would you go about taking the string between header tags, for example, printing `Hello, world!`, out of `<h1>Hello, world!</h1>`:

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen

#example URL that includes an <h> tag: http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/
userAddress = input("Enter a website URL: ")

webPage = urllib.request.urlopen(userAddress)

list = []

while webPage != "":
    webPage.read()
    list.append()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an *HTML Parser*. For example, [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(webPage)
print(soup.find("h1").get_text(strip=True))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> url = "http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/"
>>> webPage = urlopen(url)
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(webPage, "html.parser")
>>> print(soup.find("h1").get_text(strip=True))
How To Use H1-H6 HTML Elements Properly
```

---

> I'm not allowed to use any additional libraries, aside from what comes with python. Does python come with the ability to parse HTML, albeit in a less efficient way?

If you are, for some reason, not allowed to use third-parties, you can use a [built-in `html.parser` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html). Some people also use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to parse HTML. It is not always a bad thing, but you have to be very careful with that, see:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any additional libraries, aside from what comes with python. Does python come with the ability to parse HTML, albeit in a less efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/html.parser.html?highlight=htmlparser) is your best friend to deal with that issue.

There are related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804148/parsing-html-to-get-text-inside-an-element) which  already exist and cover your needs.