# Beginner Python Webscraping

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python. I am working on a webscraping project. In the project, i want to look up the meaning and POS of some words from cambridge dictionary and export them into excel.

And this is my code:

```
pip install bs4
pip install requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers = {"User-Agent" : "xxxxxxx"}
r=requests.get('https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/happy', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
POS = soup.find_all("span", class_="pos dpos")
print(POS)
```

result:
`[<span class="pos dpos" title="A word that describes a noun or pronoun''.>adjective</span>, <span class="pos dpos" title="A word that describes a noun or pronoun.''>adjective</span>]`

For the result, I only want to get the word 'adjective'. But I don't know how to do that, is there anyone can help me? Many Thanks.

Comment: Welcome @pyt. Please follow this for asking question  : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can parse the HTML like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804148/parsing-html-to-get-text-inside-an-element

Answer (score 0):

First off: Remove the `pip install` commands from your script. Installing a library is only required once. Then you can use it by importing it, as you did in line 3 and 4.

You have used the command you're looking for in your code. It is the `.text`.
Store your span inside a variable and then call it by `varname.text`.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with the other answer, you should remove the 2 lines:

```
     pip install bs4
     pip install requests
```

as they are not needed. Also, your problem is that the variable POS is a list, with 2 "span" tags. What you can do, is iterate through the list, each time printing out the contents. Like this:

```
    for div in POS: 
        print(div.text)
```

This should print "adjective" twice, once for each element, if you only want to print it for a specific div, you'll need to access it via index, but you can then call the ".text" again to get the text.

The reason that you're getting a list is because when calling find_all, by a class name you will get a list returned, as class names are not unique to HTML elements.

Hope this helps :)